# No route matches [GET] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to rails so it may sound quite naive.I'm getting this error

```
No route matches [GET] "/"
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
    match 'welcome/contact' => 'welcome#index'
end
```

Here is my controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
      redirect_to :action => :contact
   end
   def contact

   end
end
```

And i have a contact.html.erb in my app/view/welcome/.What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you want to do. But I think you want your view Welcome/contact as your index page, if this is correct, you only have to change your routes.rb file like this:

```
root to: 'welcome#contact'
```

and you have to remove the index.html file from the public folder.

On the other hand, you can read more of rails routes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Sure dat will work.But i want to redirect to a particular page using redirect_to inside the controller.Is it possible?

Comment: Try this   match 'welcome/contact', to: 'welcome#contact', via: :get

Comment: do u mean adding "match 'welcome/contact', to: 'welcome#contact', via: :get" to route.rb well in dat case i'm getting some syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a route for the actions other than CRUD actions in controller.This will solve the issue for all actions.

```
match ':controller(/:action)'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to RENDER the contact page, not to redirect to another controller and action.

Just put the code in the contact view into the `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb` file, and live happily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a **contact** action to your **WelcomeController**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
     redirect_to :action => :contact
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

Comment: make sure you have root :to => 'welcome#index' at the top of your routes.rb file